# How to set the width of a gridview's command column in edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've extended a gridview so that it can insert new row. When the gridview is inserting a new row, I want the command linkbutton to display **Add** (instead of **Update**). So I converts the command column from databound to template field. I've set the width of the column to 100px so that it contains both LinkButton.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Width = "100px">
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, when the row enter in edit mode, the size is not 100px. Linkbuttons are not next to each other anymore but one on the top of the other. How do I keep the width of the command column to 100px even in edit mode?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Modifying the wrap property to false in the TelplateField Properties editor has solved part of the propblem. Both LinkButtons are not one on the top of the other anymore. Now they are next to each other even in EDIT mode. But I still can't set the width of the column to 100px in EDIT mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but you could force the width for every cell using your GridView's `OnRowDataBound` event:

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"...
```

**C#**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // regardless of edit mode or DataControlRowType
    e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 100;
}
```

Assuming your `TemplateField` has a column index of 0 in your GridView.